# Define regular expressions in terms of each other

Tags: regex, recursion, context-free-grammar

In JavaScript, is it possible to define regular expressions in terms of other regular expressions, so that the each of the regular expressions are recursively defined?

For example, I would want to use these regular expressions (defined in terms of each other) to represent a small part of the grammar of the JavaScript programming language:

```
<functionDefinition> = function <functionName>(<parameterList>){statementList}
<statementList> = (<functionDefinition>| ... other valid statements go here ... ) //a series of JavaScript statements or function definitions

//each of these regular expressions are defined in terms of the others, allowing them to be infinitely nested
```

Comment: Another example of mutually-defined regular expressions is found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus-Naur_form#Example I wonder if it would be possible to define regular expressions in terms of each other in JavaScript.

Comment: What you're asking for is a [*context-free grammar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).  Regexes don't describe CFGs, in general, so it's the wrong tool here.  You need a proper parser (although I don't know Javascript, I'm confident in saying there must be existing parsing libraries out there...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Would it be possible to check whether a string matches a context-free grammar? I think I may have misused the phrase "regular expression" in my original question.

Comment: You can create a parser for your grammar with [jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/)

Comment: @AndersonGreen: With an appropriate parser, yes.  But a regex on its own cannot.

Answer (score 1):

> In JavaScript, is it possible to define regular expressions in terms of other regular expressions, so that the each of the regular expressions are recursively defined?

No, that is not possible using JavaScript's regex implementation.

You'll need a parser (generator) for that. Possible JS options are:

- Jison: http://zaach.github.com/jison/
- PEG.js: http://pegjs.majda.cz/